# how to include module in angualar js to remove error module not found?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am make simple app to display only header using angular js .here is my code
http://plnkr.co/edit/dplJ6sf4kgiwJ5pXu4GE?p=preview
It is showing only **"home" header**
I make same code in computer and install karma and everything ..

my issue is I am not able to test it's controller .I am getting this error

```
 Failed to instantiate module app.home due to:
        Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.home' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/nomod?p0=app.home
            at /Users/naveenkumar/Documents/ionic_work/SimpleDemo/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
```

I make **karma.conf.js** like that

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Fri Dec 18 2015 19:53:32 GMT+0530 (IST)

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [

        'bower_components/angular/angular.js' ,
        'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js' ,

        'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js' ,
        'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js' ,

        'app/**/.js',
        'app/**/*.html',
      'test/**.js'
    ],


    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
        'app/**/*.html':['ng-html2js']
    },

      ngHtml2JsPreprocessor:{
          moduleName:'templates'

    },

    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultanous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

**I do testing like this**

```
describe('check value',function(){

    var controller,
        $scope,
        $rootScope;
    beforeEach(function(){
        module('app.home')

        inject(function($injector){
            $rootScope=$injector.get('$rootScope');
            $scope=$rootScope.$new();
            controller=$injector.get('$controller')('homecntrl',{$scope:$scope});

        })

    })



    //it('check   value after click',function(){
    //    controller.clickbtn();
    //    expect(controller.message).toEqual('test');
    //})

    it('check  init',function(){
        expect(controller.message).toBeUndefined();
    })
    it('check fine',function(){
        expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })


})
```

Comment: In your index.html file it appears you import your controller before your modules. I can't get the tests to run in your plunker so I can't confirm, but I have a hunch that if you rearrange the order of the javascript tags to put the home.controller.js tag below the app.js and router.js tags in index.html you should fix that error.

Comment: ok I will check and update you

Comment: is there any way to test this app online

Comment: can we test this in this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/MZKNxvsJdfZF2wazYMOf?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, seems to work now.

Comment: Sorry I meant the plunker you provided

Comment: i also provide one plunker where you test controller..can we test my example there

Comment: Got it! WIll explain in answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98455/discussion-between-user944513-and-mike).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was two fold in your index.html file.

The first problem was that you imported your controller before you imported your modules in the HTML file. The second problem arose where the Karma version you imported did not match the angular version you were using.

Modules imported before controller

```
<script src="controller/home.controller.js"></script>
<script src="router/router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

Karma set to Angular version 1.4.8, but Angular is version 1.2.16

```
<script data-require="angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

When importing the scripts for an Angular app, you must have module dependencies imported before the module themselves and finally all controllers, directives and services must be imported after the module they are attributed to. 'app' is dependant on 'app.home' so 'app.home' is imported before 'app'. 'homeCntrl' is attributed to the module 'app' so 'app' is imported before 'homeCntrl'.

Rearrange to be as follows:

```
<script src="router/router.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller/home.controller.js"></script>
```

And finally update your version of Karma to match the version of Angular you're using.

```
<script data-require="angular.js" data-semver="1.2.16" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.min.js"></script>
```

plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xzvhXHPoUdulOM9clOkQ?p=preview

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't fork the test plunkr right away but hopefully I can that soon.

Comment: ..could you please edit one more thing...what is the sequence of importing the file. first module then router -then controller  then directive in index file ?

Comment: still facing a issue in my computer do you have some personal  ID.I don't know where I am doing wrong in my computer file.Please that is same code I am running in my pc ..but test is not successfully excecuted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98456/discussion-between-user944513-and-mike).